# Unit Root Test for Panel Data (strongly balanced with gaps)

Tags: statistics, stata, panel-data

I have a data set of 17 countries for the years 2000 to 2019.

`Country Year LNFPI LNFDILAG INFL POL CRD GDP KAOPEN EXC Y1 C1 ny1 t1`

in this data `LNFPI` is dependent variable and want to test if it is stationary. `Y1` was transformed from string to year. `C1` is encoded. When the first panel was created it showed (unbalanced with 140 gaps). I created `ny1` and `t1` to remove the gaps.

Now the panel shows (Strongly balanced with gaps).

First, I ran

```
xtunitroot fisher LNFPI, dfuller lag(1)
```

it returned `r(2000)` error

Second, I ran Levin-Lin-Chu test for the `LNFPI`
it returned

```
r(498) 
Levin-Lin--Chiu test cannot have gaps in data
```

Comment: Your second question answers itself as you say you have gaps and that test can't be run in that circumstance. What years are represented in the data?

Comment: Btw: The test is called Levin–Lin–Chu (Levin–Lin–Chu (2002)), not  Levin–Lin–Chiu even if it seems the error message by Stata contains a typo.